# Add logo to flexdashboard

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am having trouble adding my company logo to a flexdashboard output. I have looked into the issue and tried using a relative path, and resized my image to 48x48. I am still getting a broken html image when I run the document. Does anyone have any ideas of what could be wrong? This is my YAML:

```
title: "title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    source_code: embed
    logo: FoodBev.png
runtime: shiny
```

Also, the image is in my working directory. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your header works fine for my test. Be sure that the image is in the same folder as the RMD file.

Comment: Oh. That's it. My image wasn't in the same folder as the RMD file. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add custom.css file to directory ----> than, edit through notepad and add the code below:

```
img{
     max-width:48px;
     max-height:48px;
}
```

Good Luck